# Mongodb Sharding Backup / Restore

Tags: php, mongodb, distributed, mongoose

We are using mongodb sharding in production server and having 2 sharding and 3 replica set including arbitor on each shard. Records also distributed based on write request. But we have to know how will take a backup, because we are having more then 50Lks records in mondodb. So we need to take a records. Actually at present we are taking backup using mongodump in each shard server using primary IP and port.

Each time we need to take a backup on each shard server, incase on future i will add one more shard the same process we need to do on that server also. So please share your input if any other possiblities using mongos.

Regards,
Kumaran

Answer (score 2):

Here's some python code that creates consistent mongodb sharded cluster backups using LVM snapshots: https://github.com/knyar/mongoclusterscripts/tree/master/mongo-backup

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this:

[Backing Up Sharded Cluster](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Backing+Up+Sharded+Cluster).

In short:

- for small clusters you can just use `mongodump` against `mongos`.
- backing up larger clusters will involve running `mongodump` on individual shards.